# Scientific Linux 6.3 run evince in SELinux sandbox

Tags: rhel, selinux

I'm trying to run evince in the SELinux sandbox:

```
sandbox -X /usr/bin/evince Unixforpoets.pdf
```

but after waiting for minutes nothing happens, console doesn't outputs anything. So I collected the logs (/var/log/messages):

```
Sep 30 12:32:14 HOSTNAME kernel: type=1400 audit(1349001134.585:23466): avc:  denied  { name_bind } for  pid=22229 comm="Xephyr" src=6081 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:sandbox_xserver_t:s0:c310,c1018 tcontext=system_u:object_r:varnishd_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

packages installed:

```
rpm -qa | egrep -i "policycoreutils-python|policycoreutils-sandbox|Xephyr|selinux"
selinux-policy-targeted-3.7.19-155.el6_3.4.noarch
libselinux-utils-2.0.94-5.3.el6.x86_64
selinux-policy-3.7.19-155.el6_3.4.noarch
xorg-x11-server-Xephyr-1.10.6-1.sl6.x86_64
libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6.i686
libselinux-python-2.0.94-5.3.el6.x86_64
policycoreutils-python-2.0.83-19.24.el6.x86_64
policycoreutils-sandbox-2.0.83-19.24.el6.x86_64
libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6.x86_64
```

..I'm thinking about the bug I found when googling:

```
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=798916
```

It states that this bug has been fixed in:

```
selinux-policy-3.10.0-80.fc16
```

..so..I'm using: **selinux-policy-3.7.19-155.el6_3.4.noarch** ... I have to wait until SL delivers a newer version of selinux-policy?

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't like to wait, you could submit the bug report to Scientific Linux's bugzilla to make the progress going faster.

Otherwise just download and extract the desired rpm package, extract and copy the part of evince policy to /etc/ to do a temp fix.